# Google and Chrome - are they independent?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google, bookmarks

I have a Hudl 2 tablet and am running out of space. I have just bought an SD card but it seems I am very limited with what I can move to the SD card. Also it seems I can not install new apps directly onto the SD card. So I am trying to delete as much data as possible from the existing apps.

I am considering deleting all data from the Google app but am concerned it may be linked in some way to the Chrome app and I do not want to lose my Chrome bookmarks or any ids/passwords I have in Chrome.

Will deleting all data from Google affect in any way anything I have in Chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: The Google app is your search and assistant app, it is not directly tied to Chrome and you can safely delete it's data without directly affecting Chrome. That said, unless you don't search, or want notifications from any Google service, such as reminders, weather conditions, and any of about 25 categories of notifications, it will grow and take up a lot of space over time anyway. Disabling the Google app is not recommended as it is deeply tied into the OS, and although it won't cause functional problems, the usability of it's features could be hampered.